# Insert a space in string

Tags: ruby, insert

I am trying to .insert a space before the Uppercase letter if it's found.
Here's what I came up with, but it seems like it's an infinite loop. I don't know why:

```
def solution(string)
  str = string.split("")
  str.each_with_index do |l, i|
   if l.upcase
    str.insert(l[i], " ")
   end
  end
  str.join("")
end
```

please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: `if l.upcase` means "if a character _can be successfully converted_ to uppercase", this is not the same as "if a character _is_ upper case". You're effectively trying to add a space in front of the first character that can be converted to uppercase, this shifts the character's position forward. With the next iteration of the loop you re-test the same character and add another space, and so on…

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @UrsaDK is right. Try replacing `if l.upcase` with `if ('A'..'Z').include?(l)`. you should experience an infinite loop anyway though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's often a bad idea changing the object you're looping on. You insert a space before the upcase letter you found, so the next iteration you found the upcase letter again and everything repeats.

In this case regular expression seems to fit nicely

```
def solution(string)
  string.gsub(/[[:upper:]]/, ' \0')
end
```

Comment: If the string is large, then using a regex will also be much more efficient and I imagine faster (untested) then looping through all the characters of the string.

Comment: Alternate syntax: `.gsub(/([A-Z])/, ' \1')`, or even: `.gsub(/[A-Z]/, ' \0')`

Comment: And you may want to use `[[:upper:]]` to match non-ASCII uppercase characters, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also thanks for explaining why the infinite loop happens

Comment: my pleasure sir

Comment: ...or `.gsub(/(?=[[:upper:]])/, ' ')`, which replaces a zero-width position before each capital letter with a space.

Comment: Great one Cary :)